# How to prevent telerik rad buttons from having scrolling issues

Tags: html, telerik, telerik-radbutton

[image]I'm trying to fix an issue with a telerik rad button that occurs when scrolling after documents have been selected for uploading. The Select Files button stays at the top when scrolling which is what I want but the second button (Upload) does not stay at the top and instead scrolls and covers up the files that have been added via the Select Files button.

Here is the part of the code along with an image of the actual upload screen.

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="padding: 10px 0">
                <div class="col-lg-1" >
                    <telerik:RadAsyncUpload RenderMode="Lightweight" 
                                            ID="RadUpload1" 
                                            runat="server" 
                                            MultipleFileSelection="Automatic" 
                                            ManualUpload="False" 
                                            DropZones=".DropZone1" 
                                            OnClientValidationFailed ="OnClientValidationFailed"
                                            PostbackTriggers="btnUpload"
                                            HideFileInput="False"
                                            UploadedFilesRendering="BelowFileInput"
                                            OnClientFilesUploaded="onClientFilesUploaded"
                                            OnClientFileUploading="onClientFileUploading">
                        <Localization Select="Select files"></Localization>
                    </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <telerik:RadButton RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" Text="Upload" ID="btnUpload" Enabled ="false"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="DropZone1">
                <p>Drop Files Here</p>
            </div>
```

[Example snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t1LC.png)

Comment: Bumping this post in hopes of getting a response.

Comment: Inspect the button CSS with the DevTools Inspector and look for position: relative style as explained at https://www.telerik.com/forums/rad-button-controls-scroll-issue.

Comment: @RumenJekov I've checked those pages and attempted to apply the changes but it doesn't seem to do anything. Those pages also make it seem like this is a bug isolated to internet explorer but I'm having this issue in Chrome.

Comment: @RumenJekov I've added a picture to the main post showing how I'm still having the issue even with the position set to relative.

Comment: Temporarily remove the page stylesheet and see whether the problem still persists? If it went away examine the CSS classes until you find out which one is causing the scrolling issue. If you can provide a Fiddler Jam cap it will help me to research it further - https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/telerik-product-integration/capture-issues-with-fiddler-jam.

Comment: If you decide to send a Fiddler Jam capture, please follow the instructions at https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/integration-with-other-telerik-products/common-capture-issues-with-fiddler-jam. You can download the extension from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fiddler-jam/fnkjlegmkbicdodlheligomlfbdblpfj.

Comment: Note: If there is sensitive data or it is a sensitive project, it will be better to post the Fiddler Cap in a private telerik.com ticket.

Comment: @RumenJekov here's a link to the Fiddler. Hopefully I used it correctly.

https://jam.getfiddler.com/sessions/49c7bceb-76cd-4eb5-85ca-dcfe78d472c3?t=j35KBfZfhDIp5bK85%2FJiCY2if212cc6tVazVzKnwAXvrvMdJzXa1ToXK3P541HLD

Comment: Thank you for the capture, but it looks like that you haven't accomplished the note in point 5 about refreshing the page and now the capture does not contain the page:

The page refresh must be from navigation to the page, otherwise the browser will use the requests from cache and will not include them in the capture

Comment: Please refresh the page and send a new log.

Comment: @RumenJekov thank you again for the response. I will work on trying the capture again today and send the results.

Comment: Sure, please take your time!